# How can I make a field required based in other field value with Zod?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, zod

I'm trying to validate a form with Zod and react-hook-form, and I need to make some fields required based on the value of other field. Here is my schema:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
    cli_rut: z.string(),
    cli_persona_natural: z.enum(["SI", "NO"]),
    cli_nombres: z.string().optional(),
    cli_apellido_paterno: z.string().optional(),
    cli_apellido_materno: z.string().optional(),
    cli_razon_social: z.string().optional(),
    cli_estado: z.string().default("ACTIVO").optional(),
});
```

in this case I need to make required cli_nombres, cli_apellido_materno, and cli_apellido_paterno if cli_persona_natural = "SI", any ideas of how can i do it? Thanks

I'm expecting the fields to be required if cli_persona_natural is "SI"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`superRefine`](https://zod.dev/?id=superRefine) method to specify additional constraints like this, or you could use `discriminatedUnion` in this case and end up with slightly stronger types.

### Super Refine Approach:

```js
const formSchema = z
  .object({
    cli_rut: z.string(),
    cli_persona_natural: z.enum(["SI", "NO"]),
    cli_nombres: z.string().optional(),
    cli_apellido_paterno: z.string().optional(),
    cli_apellido_materno: z.string().optional(),
    cli_razon_social: z.string().optional(),
    cli_estado: z.string().default("ACTIVO").optional(),
  })
  .superRefine((data, ctx) => {
    if (data.cli_persona_natural === "SI") {
      if (data.cli_nombres === undefined) {
        // I took a best guess at the messages but it's not my native language
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: "El campo nombres es requerido",
        });
      }
      if (data.cli_apellido_paterno === undefined) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: "El campo apellido paterno es requerido",
        });
      }
      if (data.cli_apellido_materno === undefined) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: "El campo apellido materno es requerido",
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

### Discriminated Union Approach

```
import { z } from "zod";

const baseSchema = z.object({
  cli_rut: z.string(),
  cli_razon_social: z.string().optional(),
  cli_estado: z.string().default("ACTIVO").optional(),
});

const personaNaturalSchema = z.object({
  cli_persona_natural: z.literal("SI"),
  cli_nombres: z.string(),
  cli_apellido_paterno: z.string(),
  cli_apellido_materno: z.string(),
});

// Again no clue if this naming makes sense in practice
const personaJuridicaSchema = z.object({
  cli_persona_natural: z.literal("NO"),
  cli_nombres: z.string().optional(),
  cli_apellido_paterno: z.string().optional(),
  cli_apellido_materno: z.string().optional(),
});

const formSchema = z
  .discriminatedUnion("cli_persona_natural", [
    personaNaturalSchema,
    personaJuridicaSchema,
  ])
  .and(baseSchema);

console.log(
  formSchema.safeParse({
    cli_persona_natural: "SI",
    cli_rut: "12345678",
    cli_nombres: "John",
    cli_apellido_paterno: "Steve",
    cli_apellido_materno: "Tessa",
  })
); // success
console.log(
  formSchema.safeParse({
    cli_persona_natural: "NO",
    cli_rut: "12345678",
  })
); // success
console.log(
  formSchema.safeParse({
    cli_persona_natural: "SI",
    cli_rut: "12345678",
  })
); // failure
```

This approach has a benefit with the types. If you check the value of `cli_persona_natural` you will get type inference about whether or not the other fields are required.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did that and it worked!